# how to curve layout corner?

Tags: android

this is my nested layout how do i change its corner to curve??
image url 1 is a sample i want to do curve like that which implement inblack berry
image url 2 is my android code how do i curve layout like that??
url1 is https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJfnP.jpg
url 2 is   https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrAFf.jpg

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"

    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
    android:paddingRight="3dip"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"

        android:background="#333333"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMiniStatement"
            style="@style/HomeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button1"
            android:onClick="onClickFeature"
            android:text="MINI STATEMENT" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBalanceInquiry"
            style="@style/HomeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button2"
            android:onClick="onClickFeature"
            android:text="Balance Inquiry" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUtilityBalanceInquiry"
            style="@style/HomeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button3"
            android:onClick="onClickFeature"
            android:text="Utility Balance Inquiry" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want to curve my internet layout corners which is in image url 2 is my android applicaton image i want to curve it like image url 1

Comment: It looks like you want to find or create a 9patch image to use as the `background` for your layout.

Comment: It's just a PNG image with a border that defines stretchable and content areas. Android Doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 7):

In `res/drawable` create a new file (curved_bg.xml for example). In that file put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#333333" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

In your layout file set this as the background on your inner `LinearLayout`

```
android:background="@drawable/curved_bg"
```

Comment: is help little much but is not change layout curve is draw curve line